# Babel ie8 new ClassName throw 'Cannot call a class as a function'

Tags: babeljs

Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

webpack.config.js：

```
{
            test: /\.js[x]?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,  
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015-loose', 'stage-0'], 
                cacheDirectory: true, 
                //cacheIdentifier : '.babelrc', 
                plugins: ['transform-runtime']
            }
        }
```

js code ：

```
import "babel-polyfill";

class CC{
constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
}
var c1 = new CC(1,2);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem has been solved.

Comment: plugins: ['transform-es5-property-mutators','transform-jscript']